# Python output dict to new json structure

Tags: python, json, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python and have run into a problem that I have not been able to solve despite a lot of searching and reading related posts.  Any help is much appreciated:
I have imported a json file into a dictionary that has this structure:

```
{
 "23991": {
 "5115": 10,
 "2611": 22
 },
 "43223": {
 "7252": 11,
 "4302": 2
 }
}
```

I want to save it to a new json file with this structure:

```
[
 {
  "sni": {
   "code": "23991",
   "yrken": [
     {
       "code": "5115",
       "antal": 10
     },
     {
       "code": "2611",
       "antal": 22
     }
   ]
  }
},
{
  "sni": {
   "code": "43223",
   "yrken": [
     {
       "code": "7252",
       "antal": 11
     },
     {
       "code": "4302",
       "antal": 11
     }
   ]
  }
 }
]
```

So far I have this code:

```
import os
import sys
import json

pathSNI2Yrke = "Smallsni2Yrke.json"
with open(pathSNI2Yrke) as data_file:
sni2Yrke = json.load(data_file)
#print(sni2Yrke)

for key in sni2Yrke:
    value = sni2Yrke[key]
    d = [{"sni": 
          {"snicode": key, 
           "yrken": [{ "yrkecode":list(value.keys()),
                      "antal": list(value.values())}]}}]
    j = json.dumps(d, indent=2)
    #f = open('sample.json', 'w')
    print ( j)
```

Which gives me this result:

```
[
{
  "sni": {
   "snicode": "23991",
   "yrken": [
     {
      "yrkecode": [
        "5115",
        "2611"
       ],
      "antal": [
        10,
        22
       ]
     }
    ]
  }
 }
]
[
 {
  "sni": {
   "snicode": "43223",
   "yrken": [
     {
      "yrkecode": [
        "7252",
        "4302"
       ],
       "antal": [
         11,
         2
       ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
]
```

As you see this isn't a correct json structure, and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the structure right. The output goes all the way back to the root element so I get ...][... instead of ...},{.... between the "sni" blocks
If you have tips on how the code could be better or a better way of achieving the result please let me have them.

Comment: You are saving it as a list. What do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some nested [comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you can do the following:

```
> d = {'43223': {'4302': 2, '7252': 11}, '23991': {'5115': 10, '2611': 22}}

> d2 = [
  {'sni': 
    {'code': k1, 
     'yrken': [{'code': k2, 'antal': v2} for k2, v2 in v1.items()]
    }
  } 
  for k1, v1 in d.items()
]

> print json.dumps(d2, indent=1)
[
 {
  "sni": {
   "code": "43223", 
   "yrken": [
    {
     "antal": 2, 
     "code": "4302"
    }, 
    {
     "antal": 11, 
     "code": "7252"
    }
   ]
  }
 }, 
 {
  "sni": {
   "code": "23991", 
   "yrken": [
    {
     "antal": 10, 
     "code": "5115"
    }, 
    {
     "antal": 22, 
     "code": "2611"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: This worked for me! I just replaced the d= in my code with your d2= and put used 'for k1, v1 in sni2Yrke.items()' instead of 'd.items()' Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Enjoy:

```
result = []

for code, dct in your_json.items():
    yrken = []
    for c, antal in dct.items():
        yrken.append({
            "code": c,
            "antal": antal
        })
    result.append({
        "sni": {
            "code": code,
            "yrken": yrken
        }
    })

print(result)
```

Comment: @Formalhaut This worked really well too. I am going to pick this apart so I will understand it better. :)